# Custom UIButton in UIscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am using `xcode 4.6` to develop an app. Here i want to add UIButton programmatically to UIscrollview. This is the code i follow.

```
UIButton *bt =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[bt setTitle:@"Custom Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
bt.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
bt.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.mainscrollview addSubview:bt];
[self.mainscrollview bringSubviewToFront:bt];
```

Now the problem is that Button gets disappeared (technically its textcolor becomes white) on click. I checked keeping UIscrollview color to red that th button was still in the view but i cant get the reason why its text color changed and how do i undo dis. 
Basically I wan to create a clickable link using UIbutton. 
I know uitextview approach (datadetectortype) but its of no use as i want to show different text in the label for the link and the actual link.

Note: The textcolor doesnt change back to blue and remains white only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code

```
UIButton *bt =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
bt.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0);
[bt setTitle:@"Custom Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
bt.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
bt.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.scrollTest addSubview:bt];

-(void)userTappedOnLink:(UIButton*)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Test  ..");

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeBtnTextColor:) withObject:sender afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void)changeBtnTextColor:(UIButton*)btn
{
  btn.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanx for ur answer.. this was a gr8 help bro! Now works all perfect.

Answer (score 2):

use below code you will get your solution

```
UIButton *bt =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[bt setTitle:@"Custom Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[bt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[bt setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.mainscrollview addSubview:bt];
[self.mainscrollview bringSubviewToFront:bt];
```

Comment: Well,Your code worked fine provided i keep button as normal and not custom. But now when i click on the button the event is being called but there is no visual feel that button is clicked.

Comment: then set other color for title as UIControlStateHighlighted
Like

[bt setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: In that case colour always remains blue. but i again changed colour in the called function of that button and that gave click effect when button is touched.

Comment: do you want when you click first time title become red until you click button again. and on second time clicked title become blue. do you want like that?

Comment: No NO. I simply want click feel whenever user clicks the button.. i have already found its solution. So what i do is  write this line in the function which is being called on button tap.   sender.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];  here sender is argument of the function being called. of course this all is keeping in mind that i am writing this line                              [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; while initialising button

Comment: you have to write this line below [bt setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; line in same place where you declare button.

Comment: use another color for highlighted state and for normal state

Comment: Yeah Have done that.also have changed the colour which is different.thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
[bt setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Problem is you are set Title to titleLabel and you are changing textColor of buttonTitle color.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

check Button's Fram .. is it valid or not ??
and remove `bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` line from your code.